# How Machine Learning intgreate with Big Data?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science

1. How machine learning integrate with big data?
2. What is the difference between machine learning and MapReduce?
3. What is the main concept should I consider?
4. What one of the 3 (Supervised Learning, Unsupervised Learning, Reinforcement Learning) is the main for decision making
5. What are the differences of decision making using big data in let's say healthcare and Smart Cities?
6. And what is the relation between big data and deep learning as one of the machine learning techniques?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres my quick and to the point opinions:

1. Machine learning methods "learn" through a method called gradient descent, which is typically very data inefficient, but very general, easy to implement, and does not need much prior knowledge of the data.  In order for this method to truly shine, you need a lot of data to get accurate models; hence, a lot of machine learning methods need big data.
2. Machine learning is a field of artificial intelligence aimed to give the machine abilities to learn concepts without *explicitly* being programmed to do so.  MapReduce is a distributed computing method that can be used to speed up machine learning training, or any computationally heavy tasks.
3. The main concept of machine learning is which machine learning algorithms should be used for specific tasks.  For example, supervised learning is used for **regression** and **classification** and are applied to data sets that are **labeled**.  Regression algorithms are used to predict continuous variables and classification algorithms are used for categorical variables.  An example of a continuous task is predicting the real estate price of a particular house.  An example of a categorical task would be predicting if the picture is a dog or cat.  
    
   In unsupervised learning, the two main families are **principal components** and **clustering** and they are mainly used for **unlabeled** data sets.  Here, the machine must find the optimal segregation of the data.
4. Reinforcement learning would definitely be the decision making algorithm; RL was designed for optimal control and optimal decision making after all, since its fundamental algorithm is the Bellman Equation.
5. Decision making is fundamentally based on the problem you're trying to solve.  For example, if I am trying to create cookies, I can either make my cookies taste *damn* good, but spend a lot more money, or I can make cookies that taste ok but spend significantly less. Depending on the market I am trying to serve, my decision would be significantly different. 
    
   Since the task for either was not properly defined here, I will make some assumptions.  In health care, one big one would be treatment of individuals with kidney failure.  Here, patients need to go to the hospital for 2-3 hours every 2 days to get their blood cleaned medically through a method called dialysis.  Here, we can build a reinforcement learning controller to control the flow rate, medication, etc, of the dialysis process to both shorten the blood cleaning process AND allow the patient to experience less pain.  I have personally worked on this project.  The decision making for the ML algorithm here is the flow rate and medication amount, among other things. 
    
   In a smart city, the agent might instead want to optimize traffic flow or electricity usage.  For traffic flow, the agent's decision making would be when to make which lights red to minimize the overall total wasted time in traffic.  For electricity usage, the agent would want the electricity to travel at the smallest distance so electricity wastage is minimized.
6. Big data and deep learning's relationship is same as #1, except, replace the "a lot" in my last sentence with all.  Deep learning models are highly parameterized, and require an insane amount of data to be fully accurate and usable (assuming your network is sufficiently deep). However, given sufficient data, its accuracy and abilities are undeniable. The figure below from SumoLogic shows an useful visualization of the change in accuracy in the model vs the amount of data fed into different machine learning algorithms.

[image]

Comment: Well explanation, thank you
When the concept of machine learning shows in big data like is MapReduce has anything to do with machine learning algorithms, and if it yes, when?
Let's say that we have an application implemented like healthcare in big data on how machine learning has to do with it and when? like does it show when the big data process (ingestion, processing, and storage) end? or it helps the big data process (ingestion, processing, and storage) do their work?
In the application, I mention what should I consider in machine learning using big data?

Comment: for point 6 about deep learning is it always about how data affect the performance or there is something else?

Comment: MapReduce has nothing to do with ML algorithms.  I don't understand your 2nd point about healthcare, but there are many applications in health care.  You can use ML to identify for cancer in x-ray images for example.  ML applications are the same in all industries where you need to build a data pipeline. For deep learning, all it means is that you add more parameters to your model to improve its predictive capabilities, but you need more data to train the additional parameters.  If you lack data, the parameters won't be trained and would reduce accuracy.

Comment: Do you mean that Machine Learning happened to the data stored (x-ray image) in HDFS and has nothing to do with MapReduce? Then the reduction algorithms like PCA what the use of them in Machine Learning? (though we use them in MapReduce)

Comment: MapReduce is a parallel computing algorithm and has nothing to do with reducing the dimensions of your data.  PCA is a machine learning algorithm to linearly extract principal components of a data set based on covariance.  The idea of PCA is to project the original data linearly onto a subspace that has lower dimension, while retaining all useful features. PCA on a large data set might require a lot of time, so you could use MapReduce to reduce the amount of computation time, but MapReduce has nothing to do with reducing the data set dimension, PCA does.